# Degree of T-conductor larger than zero but less than the full vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am from Physics background. I have been trying to figure out this proof for sometime now. Can anyone please solve it?

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ and let $W$ be an invariant subspace of $T$. For any $\alpha\in V$ show that,

$0<max_{\alpha}\text{deg }s(\alpha;W)\leq\text{dim }V$,

where $s(\alpha;W)$ is the $T$-conductor of $\alpha$ into $W$.

For clarification of the term $T$-conductor: The set of all polynomial functions of $T$, that take a vector $\alpha$ into an invariant space $W$ forms an ideal. The minimal polynomial (i.e. least common factor) of that ideal is called $T$-conductor of $\alpha$ into $W$ and denoted by $s(\alpha;W)$. It can be found in the book of Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question doesn't correspond exactly to the title. I would have thought of something like $\dim(W)\leqslant\deg s(\alpha;W)\leqslant\dim(V)$. Plus you wrote "for any $\alpha\in V$" and then you have an $\alpha$ in your $\max$.

Comment: True. That was an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that, as a consequence the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, the characteristic polynomial $f$ satisfies $\operatorname{deg}(f) = \dim V$ and $f \in s(\alpha;W)$ for all $\alpha \in V$.

Comment: If $T=Id_V$ and $W$ is a strict subspace of $V$, then $f(T)\alpha\notin W$ if $\alpha\notin W$. By the way, by Nik's notation, $s(\alpha;W)$ is not a set (not the aforementioned ideal).

Comment: @PhilippeMalot No, characteristic polynomial function of any Operator is Zero. This is Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for the answer, but I am mainly stuck in the equality sign.

Comment: @Nik: my mistake. I wrote too quickly. $f$ is in the ideal $I(\alpha;W)=\{g\in\mathbb{K}[X]\colon g(T)\alpha\in W\}$ and $s(\alpha; W)$ divides $f$, so $\deg(s(\alpha;W))\leqslant\deg(f)$.

Comment: @Nik I don't understand what you mean when you say that you're "stuck in the equality sign".

Comment: @Nik What makes you think that there will necessarily be such a vector?  At the very least, the question statement is not looking for any such proof.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I meant that I am not being able to prove that there exists a vector $\beta$ s.t. the equality sign holds. i.e.

$\text{deg} s(\beta;W)= \text{dim} V$.

But I suspect this statement might be wrong for a general operator and an arbitrary subspace. May be I am making some mistake somewhere. Actually I am stuck in the proof of Cyclic Decomposition Theorem in Chap 7 of Linear Algebra book by Hoffman-Kunze and these are intermediate steps in that.

Comment: @Nik In an example such as $T = 0$ or $T = \operatorname{Id}_V$ and $\subsetneq V$, there will be no such vector.  More generally: for $W = \{0\}$ we can only find a vector satisfying $\operatorname{deg} s(\beta;W) = \dim V$ if the minimal polynomial of $T$ is equal to the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @Nik perhaps you should ask a question about the cyclic decomposition theorem, then

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yeah this is correct. Thanks a lot and I think I should again look into the proof in more detail and come back again, if that doesn't help. Thanks once again.